# Regular pentagon and an exterior point

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

> *ABCDE* is a regular pentagon. *F* is an exterior point (outside the
> pentagon) such that *BFC*, *BFD*, *DFA* and *AFE* angles are equal. What is
> the value of *BFC* angle?

[image: The picture should look like this]

At this moment I have found that:

- *CF*=*EF* (it is possible to draw a circle around a regular pentagon - the tangent segments drawn from one point are equal)
- *BF*=*AF* (from *BFA* triangle which is isosceles)

Also I have some combinations of values for different angles, but nothing that is leading to an answer.

Comment: $FD$ is perp bisector of $AB$. So if $FD$ intersects $CE$ at $H$ and $AB$ at $G$, you can find $FD$ in terms of $\tan x$ using $\triangle FBG$ and then an equation in $\tan x$ using $\triangle FCH$

Answer (score 2):

Draw from $C$ the perpendicular to $BF$, to meet line $FD$ at $H$. Line $BF$ is then the perpendicular bisector of $CH$, hence $BH=BC=AB$. It follows that $ABH$ is an equilateral triangle, so that $\angle CBH=108°-60°=48°$. We have then $\angle HBF=24°$ and $\angle FHB=150°$, finally giving  the desired result: $\angle HFB=180°-24°-150°=6°$.

[image]

Comment: I agree this is the correct result, but can we assume we initially know the precise location of $F$? I read the question to mean we should construct $F$ from the information given. This isn't a problem: $H$ is the point inside the pentagon where the circle centred at $B$ passing through $C$ intercepts the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, and we can proceed from there.

Comment: @nickgard I took for granted that $F$ must lie on the common perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $CE$. The question, however, only asks for the value of the angle, assuming that $F$ exists.

Comment: @nickgard In fact it is not difficult (but tedious) to prove that $F$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $$.